# Get the value from Output parameter C#

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, output

hi i'm try to  create sp in sql with output value 
this is the code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SelectHospital_IfExiste_Department]
@HospitalDepartmentID INT,
@IfExiste INT OUTPUT 
AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
IF NOT EXISTS  (SELECT c.DeptID FROM Clinic c WHERE DeptID=@HospitalDepartmentID )
BEGIN


    SET @IfExiste=0

SELECT
    [HospitalDepartmentID],
    [NAME]
FROM
    [dbo].[Hospital_Department]
WHERE
    [HospitalDepartmentID] = @HospitalDepartmentID

END

ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @IfExiste=1

SELECT
    [HospitalDepartmentID],
    [NAME]
FROM
    [dbo].[Hospital_Department]
WHERE
    [HospitalDepartmentID] = @HospitalDepartmentID
    END
```

and the C# code

```
public static Hospital_Department GetDepartmentInfo(int ID,int OutIfExist)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd;
            SqlDataReader dr;
            Hospital_Department HD = new Hospital_Department();
            using (cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_SelectHospital_IfExiste_Department", ProjectCon.GetCon()))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HospitalDepartmentID", ID);
                //cmd.Parameters.Add("@IfExiste",SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@IfExiste",SqlDbType.Int);
                cmd.Parameters["@IfExiste"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    HD.NAME = dr["NAME"].ToString();
                    HD.HospitalDepartmentID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["HospitalDepartmentID"]);
                }
                OutIfExist = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@IfExiste"].Value);
                return HD;
            }

        }
```

when i try to get the output value is always null
and i run the stored procedure in sql Was run and return the value
so plz tell me what's wrong in my code
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374193/sql-output-stored-procedures-not-working-with-executereader) has useful info:

*According to, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971497, you must close the datareader before you process the output parameters.*

Hope it helps.