# Stored Procedure returns a 0 only when on the server - not when run locally

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, webforms

I have the following code to return an id number from a database. It works fine when I run it locally, but when I put the files onto the server, while it does log the data into the DB, but it only returns a 0 and not the ID number.

`HHID` is an ID that autoincrements when I log the info to the DB.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("DB connection stuff");
SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
SqlDataReader reader;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "insert_workshop_requests";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HHID", 1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", usernameData.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nameData.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", emailData.Text);

cmd.Parameters["@HHID"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

try
{
    conn.Open();
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    HHID = System.Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@HHID"].Value);
}
catch (Exception exc)
{

}
finally
{
    if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
        conn.Close();
}
```

This is driving me crazy! Hoping someone can help, because while I've found loads of useful articles about SP that store a 0 rather than an ID, the issues are always when running locally as well. Mine working locally is making it very difficult to debug!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the code for the SP?

Comment: How does your stored procedure look like? How do you check that it returns 0 instead of your desired Id number?

Comment: @hlh3406 Also, I think you should use ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: By "locally" do you mean both the app and the database are local? If so I think you stored procedure is different on the server and does not set the output variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ExecuteReader for something that is not a SELECT. This has an interesting side effect on return parameters. Until you close the reader the values inside parameters of *Direction = Output* are not available.

[SQL OUTPUT Stored Procedures not working with ExecuteReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374193/sql-output-stored-procedures-not-working-with-executereader)

So you could close the reader, but really you should use ExecuteNonQuery for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE queries

```
conn.Open();
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
reader.Close();
HHID = System.Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@HHID"].Value);
```

or better

```
conn.Open();
int records = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
HHID = System.Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@HHID"].Value);
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

as far as i can understand, you are trying to return the id of the last entry,
for that you can use this and bind the result to a variable and return it

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

i hope this will work out